# Understanding javascript call sequence and function scopes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what is going on here. I am trying to change a variable defined outside of a function scope. I come from a Java background and this set of code has taken me by surprise

```
var dayIsEmpty = false;

selectByDate.on('end', function(result) {

    if(result.rowCount == 0) {
        console.log('isEmpty');
        dayIsEmpty = true;
    } else {
        console.log('isNotEmpty');
        dayIsEmpty = false;
    }
    console.log('isEmpty?' + dayIsEmpty);
    console.log('Finished Select from UsageByDay');
});
console.log('outside of block isEmpty?' + dayIsEmpty);
```

I noticed that

```
outside of block isEmpty? false
```

is called before any of console output defined within the function is called. First of all... what is going on? And secondly, how would you work around this.

Comment: Why do you think the function is ever being called?

Comment: Nothing to do with function scope. Everything to do with call sequence.

Comment: what's going on? asynchronous function. how to work around this? you don't, you learn to use it

Comment: The event `end` must fire first for your function to be triggered by the event handler.  That is why you see the log statement first.  HTML5 Rocks has a solid article on async programming: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/